# Dynamic queries with PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to figure out how to convert my history script from mysql_query() to PDO. I have a form with 4 input fields which you can randomly select. Which means there can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 fields selected depending on which info you're trying to get.

I've tried to query db like this:

```
$q = $db->prepare('SELECT date,
                          name,
                          action
                   FROM history
                   WHERE name = :name
                   AND action = :action');

$q->bindParam(':name', $Name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$q->bindParam(':action', $Action, $PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$q->execute();
```

But this doesn't work if I don't have any fields selected and want the whole history shown.

With mysql_query() I'd just do this:

```
mysql_query('SELECT date,
                    name,
                    action
             FROM history
             $Name
             $Action');
```

Which means if there's no $Name or $Action they're simply not included in the query.

Should I just copy/paste the old query into $q = $db-query('')? But that kind of defeats the purpose of using PDO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could always assign default values to the params which conform to the column names.

That way your query will in the default case end up as `where column = column` and when there is a value present it will be `where column = value`.

EDIT:

Of course, my logic was slightly flawed, since `bindParam` does not work that way. Instead, you should incrementally build your statement according to the params set.

```
/* Start with the most general case for the sql query.
 * The where part always evaluates to true and will thus
 * always return all rows and exists only to make appending
 * further conditions easier.
 */

$q = 'SELECT date, name, action FROM history WHERE 1';

/* Prepare a params array in any way you wish. A loop might be more
 * efficient if it is possible, but since in this example you have
 * only 2 variables, it didn't seem necessary 
 */

$params = array();
if (! empty($Name)) {
    $params['name'] = $Name;
}

if (! empty($Action)) {
    $params['action'] = $Action;
}

/* When the params array is populated, complete the sql statement by
 * appending the param names joined with ANDs 
 */

foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $q .= sprintf(' AND `%s` = :%s', $key, $key);
}

/* When the query is complete, we can prepare it */
$stmt = $db->prepare($q);

/* Then bind the values to the prepared statement 
 */

foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    // Using bindValue because bindParam binds a reference, which is
    // only evaluated at the point of execute
    $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
}

/* Now we're ready to execute */
$stmt->execute();
```

In this example, the `empty` check could've been done in the loop where we complete the sql statement, but that would've given you a less general example.

This example also leaves out the type param to `bindValue`, but that would be easily implemented, e.g. by changing the array value to an object or array having the type as a member, or by duck typing inside the assigning loop.

The query building could in this form easily be put in a function that would work for all your database querying needs, as long as you provide it the initial (general case) query along with the params array.

Comment: I tried just adding a space if the variable is empty. Didn't work.

Comment: A space is a value and will thus only match columns containing that value, but a column will always match itself.

Comment: I tried your solution in phpmyadmin, works perfectly. Now the only problem is that when I bindParam they get enclosed in ' ' which doesn't make it a column but a search word. Any ideas how to remove those ''? I'm using PDO::PARAM_STR when I bind it.

Comment: @eSiks: Oh shoot. There is an obvious fault in my logic, I updated my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me in a very understanding way. It works exactly as it should. I'll be using this approach for every search algorithm with non-static variables.

Comment: @eSiks: glad to be able to help.

Comment: @789 your edit was wrong. The loop you edited is compiling a column name and value placeholder pair. The value is injected later.