# Get Geolocations from SQL database to be used in Bing Maps

Tags: sql, geolocation, bing-maps

Basically I have a set of geolocations and other information corresponding to each point in a table in a SQL database. I have a Bing Maps website with checkboxes to set different filters for which geolocation pins should be displayed. I'm basically wondering how I can most efficiently query the database and update pins on a map, based on given checkboxes.

Alternatively, as requerying may be expensive as the table size increases, how could I load the entire database and only display certain pins based on the selected checkbox filters?

When researching this I found answers regarding GeoRSS files, but those solutions are specific to points that are all loading at once and that will continue to stay in view. It doesn't seem like filters can be applied in this process (without further requerying).

EDIT: When I say 'filters' I'm basically talking about narrowing down the currently displayed pins by things like the date the geolocation was recorded, and various other things that will use checkboxes. Let's say I have a list of restaurants and they each have their ID, geolocation, date added (to the database), and a foreign key for their type of food. I'd like to be able to select through the available food-types to limit results to Italian and Mexican restaurants but still provide the functionality of showing Chinese restaurants with the click of a button.

And to make it easy, I'll initially take all database entries in.

Comment: is there a limit to the amount of pins and checkboxes?

Comment: Could you specify filters as these will have a bearing on answering

Comment: @davidstrachan - I've edited the post above. Does it now answer your question?

Comment: Dynamic queries may be suitable. See the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538960/dynamic-queries-with-php-pdo

Comment: @davidstrachan - I've done dynamic queries before but I'm basically wondering how people typically get their data from a database then  efficiently throw it into bing maps?

Comment: I don't use Bing but with Google Maps I now use AJAX client side and PHP/MySQL server side generating JSON or XML

Comment: @davidstrachan - This is all relatively new to me. Do you have any references regarding where I could get started with the generation of xml/json with php/mysql?

Comment: I will post an Answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an SSRS Report with a Map Control to display the info on a Bing Map. That way you can use an expression in the "hidden" property of the marker to determine whether or not to show the pushpin and map your checkboxes to parameters.

See 
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240845.aspx for using a map control.

If SharePoint is an option you can have a completely interactive experience with PowerView.
Here is an introduction http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-help/maps-in-power-view-HA103005792.aspx