# PHP PDO bind dynamic field and value from search box

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to run a query using PDO prepared statements that allows me to have a user select a field and then enter value for that field, and include that in my query.

So in this basic query:

```
$sql = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM administrators WHERE Status=:Status "; 
$stmt->bindParam(':Status',$Status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Works great.

But I have a search form that allows say a user to select drop down that shows FirstName, LastName and then a text box to enter the search term

```
$sql = "SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM administrators WHERE Status=:Status **AND FIELD = TERM**";
```

I have not found any good examples online so far. Any guidance is appreciated.

I am using:

```
$params = array();
    if (!empty($SearchField) && !empty($SearchFor)) 
    {
        $params['SearchField'] = $SearchField;
        $params['SearchFor'] = $SearchFor;
    }
```

But I am getting the error:
    Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SearchField' in 'where clause''

## Updated Code:

Here is the code I am using from my form:

```
 <input id="searchtext" name="searchtext" type="text" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo GetParam('searchtext'); ?>" />   
                            <select name="searchby">
                                <option value="">Search By</option>
                                <option id="LastName" value="LastName" <?php if(GetParam('searchby') == 'LastName'){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Last Name</option>
                                <option id="FirstName" value="FirstName" <?php if(GetParam('searchby') == 'FirstName'){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>First Name</option>
                                <option id="RoleName" value="RoleName" <?php if(GetParam('searchby') == 'RoleName'){echo "selected='selected'";}?>>Role Name</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="command" value="search" />
```

and here is the code for my method:

```
public function GetAllUsers($Status = 'A',$SearchField = '',$SearchFor = '')
{
$db=DB::getInstance();
$sql = "SELECT administrators.AdminId, AdminEmail, LastName, FirstName, PrimaryPhone, CellPhone, administrators.Status, LoginDateTime, RoleName FROM administrators INNER JOIN permissions on permissions.AdminId=administrators.AdminId INNER JOIN roles on roles.RoleId=permissions.RoleId INNER JOIN sessions on sessions.AdminId=administrators.AdminId WHERE Status=:Status ";

$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':Status',$Status, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Comment: [From the very related questions list offered to you wile you were busy writnin your question and still shown in the right column on this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538960/dynamic-queries-with-php-pdo)

Comment: I tried that example earlier and it is not exactly working for me. I do not have a specific field name with a specific value, but a field that could be one of three field names and then a search field so I need it to be where $SearchField = $SearchFor. I am not getting how to bind those two into a SearchField=:SearchFor

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parameters for identifiers (table / column names, etc). You'll need to sanitise these appropriately and inject them into your query string. You can still use a parameter for the value. I'd probably also go with a set list of searchable columns. For example

```
// create a map of field key to column name mappings
$searchCols = array(
    'fn' => 'FirstName',
    'ln' => 'LastName'
);
```

When showing your form, you can use this to generate the options

```
<select name="SearchField">
    <?php foreach ($searchCols as $key => $label) : ?>
    <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($key) ?>"><?= htmlspecialchars($label) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Now use this to build your query

```
// you'll probably want some more validation around this
$searchField = $searchCols[$_POST['SearchField']];

$query = sprintf('SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM administrators WHERE Status = :Status AND `%s` = :searchTerm',
    $searchField);

// prepare statement and bind status, etc ...

$stmt->bindParam(':searchTerm', $SearchFor);
```

Comment: This does not work - I continually get an error of: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables.  I have it showing all users from the admin table, but if they want to narrow it down by last, first ... they can submit the form. I played around with a switch statement to add the correct field name in there, but that seems to defeat the purpose and I know some of my other forms will have a lot more options to search on.

Comment: @Scott You'll need to show some more of your code then. There is not enough in your question to discover what the problem is