# mysql select query using imploded values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have to following situation: I'm making a search page. The search page is populated with MySQL select query selectboxes. Therefor the name of the checkboxes are like `name="name[]"`.
To show you what I'm doing, I'll include a picture:

[image: Picture]

So if I were to check 1 Availability - like Week - the query will work perfectly. But if I choose 2 Availabilities, only the models with BOTH availabilites show instead of every model that has one of both availabilities. 
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
    $return2 = $tafel->query("SELECT DISTINCT whenpossible FROM models where arttype LIKE 'Model%'");
    while($row1 = $return2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    $whenp = $row1['whenpossible'];
    <input type="checkbox" name="when[]" value="<?= $whenp ?>"><span class="box2"><?= $whenp ?></span>
```

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST['gender'])) {
$genders = $_POST['gender'];
$gender = implode(",",$genders);
} else {
$gender = "%";
}

$select = $tafel->prepare("SELECT * FROM models 
    WHERE whenpossible LIKE :when");
$select->bindParam(':when', $when, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$select->execute();
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this so that I can choose either 1 or multiple options?

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic queries with PHP PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538960/dynamic-queries-with-php-pdo)

Comment: The main problem is that if I use both Availabilities, I get no result, instead of every model that has one of both availaibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested or facing the same problem, here is the answer:

In case IN or FIND_IN_SET aren't working for you, you can try this.

Implode your value like so:

```
if (!empty($_POST['VALUE'])) {
$value = $_POST['VALUE'];
$valueimplode = implode('|', $value)
} else {
$value = 'somethingelse'
}
```

| is very important for the SQL function. It acts like OR.
SQL as followed:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP(:valueimplode)");
$query->bindParam(':value', $valueimplode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

You will find all the results that you need.

If you have an empty value, you can do this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['VALUE'])) {
$value = $_POST['VALUE'];
$valueimplode = implode('|', $value)
} else {
$value = '%' <-- Wildcard, means EVERYTHING!!!
}
```

Then the SQL like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column REGEXP(:valueimplode) OR column LIKE :value)");
$query->bindParam(':value', $valueimplode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

% doesn't work with REGEXP so it will go to LIKE, which will then select everything in that column. Meaning, it will result everything.

I hope someone has good use for this!

Answer (score 0):

In code you build incorrect SQL command.

For your example SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%value1,%value2'
```

This is wrong code. Correct code can be

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%value1' OR field LIKE '%value2'
```

You should rewrite your code for build correct SQL

Comment: I wish I could do that, but the values are sql generated. So I never know how many values there will be.